ruby web request integrated auth/sspi
I am trying to write a ruby method that can fetch a url from a web server that requires integrated authentication.  This is on Windows and the user already has access.  I am looking to do it natively, and not exec into a powershell for performance reasons.
I see there are a few pieces
Win32::SSPI::NegotiateAuth and HTTPClient::SSPINegotiateAuth but not sure how to get this going.  Thank you so much in advance.
